# How to create openlayers3 Popup with OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud UI design

Tags: openlayers, popup

I want the look of popup in OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud to my openlayers3 popup , that makes my highlited feature more clearly and the information is shown in the popup as table form data.

Answer (score 1):

You can create such a popup using an `ol.Overlay`.  Look at the following [popup example in ol3](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html) as a start.  It already looks a lot like the original framed cloud popup.

You can control its styling / size using plain CSS.